# Manipulation of probability integrals

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $r>0$ and let $X>0$ and $Y$ be independent random variables where $Y$ has the standard exponential distribution.  Let $\mu$ denote the distribution of $X$.  Then

$$\mathbb{P}\{Y > rX\} = \int_{\mathbb{R_+}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}e^{-y}\mathbf{1}_{\{rx<y\}}dy\Big)d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}e^{-rx}d\mu=\mathbb{E}e^{-rX}.$$

This is an example taken from my probability book and I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how the first equality holds.  My guess is that it requires an application of Fubini's theorem (allowed by the independence of $X$ and $Y$ I think):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}e^{-y}\mathbf{1}_{\{rx<y\}}dy\Big)d\mu=\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}e^{-y}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}\mathbf{1}_{\{rx<y\}}d\mu\Big)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}\mathbb{P}\{y > rX\}e^{-y}dy.$$

Assuming this is correct, $\mathbb{P}\{y > rX\}$ is just the CDF of the random variable $rX$ and thus I can apply integration by parts to obtain the integral:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R_+}}e^{-y}f(y)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R_+}}f(y)dv=\int_{\Omega}f(Y)d\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}\{Y > rX\},$$

where $f$ is the PDF of $rX$ and $v$ is the measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $Y$.  Can anyone verify the correctness of this?  What concerns me the most is whether Fubini's theorem is allowed and the fact that to apply integration by parts the CDF for $rX$ has to be differentiable, but the most I know is it's right continuous, although I imagine there might be a suitable generalization using the Radon-Nikodym theorem which allows me to perform integration by parts anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a consequence of the independence assumption and Fubini's theorem. First we write the desired probability in terms of the random vector $(X,Y)$:
$$
P(Y>rX)=P((X,Y)\in A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}1_A(x,y)\,P_{(X,Y)}(\mathrm dx,\mathrm dy),
$$
where $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y>rx\}$ and $P_{(X,Y)}$ is the distribution of the vector $(X,Y)$. Now, by independence we know that $P_{(X,Y)}=P_X\times P_Y$, i.e. the distribution of $(X,Y)$ factors as a product measure of the marginal distributions. Thus we can apply Fubini's theorem, which is justified because everything is non-negative and measurable:
$$
P(Y>rX)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_A(x,y)\,P_Y(\mathrm dy)\,P_X(\mathrm dx).
$$
To arrive at the expression after the first equality in your question: you just note that $1_A(x,y)=1_{\{rx<y\}}(x,y)$ and then apply that $P_Y(\mathrm dy)=e^{-y}\,\mathrm dy$ and that $P_X=\mu$.